# Cannot insert into source table with INTEGRITY VIOLATION IGNORE

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

In a U-SQL script, we want to SELECT data from a partitioned table into a rowset, do some manipulation, and then INSERT the data back into the same table.

The following works fine:

```
@rowset =
    SELECT PartitionColumn,
           DataColumn * 2 AS DataColumn      // Some manipulation
    FROM MyTable;

INSERT MyTable (PartitionColumn, DataColumn)
ON INTEGRITY VIOLATION IGNORE
SELECT PartitionColumn,
       DataColumn
FROM @rowset;
```

However, if we add a WHERE criteria on the `PartitionColumn`, assuming we have a valid partition bucket value in `@partition1`:

```
@rowset =
    SELECT PartitionColumn,
           DataColumn * 2 AS DataColumn
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE PartitionColumn == @partition1
```

We get the following error when executing the script:

> Completed with 'Error' : 30-08-2017 10:18:32 Execution failed with
>   error '1_SV1_Extract_Split Error  {
>       "diagnosticCode":195887163,"severity":"Error",
>       "component":"RUNTIME",
>       "source":"System",
>       "errorId":"E_RUNTIME_SYSTEM_INTERNALISSUE",
>       "message":"An internal error has been reported 'Assertion failed: 'partitionDimension < vertexIndices.size()'
>
> [removed stack trace]

If we explicitly specify the partition in the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT MyTable (DataColumn)
PARTITION (@partition1)
SELECT DataColumn
FROM @rowset;
```

...the script works fine. However, we have a situation where we SELECT data from several partitions based on a range of values for the `PartitionColumn`, so we would just like to rely on implicit insertion into buckets. Is there a workaround for this?

I should note that this has only been tested on a local database using Data Lake Tools for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug (SYSTEM INTERNAL ISSUE). Can you please file an incident with either a repro if it only repros in local run, or with a failing job link if it fails in the cluster? You can also send me the information to usql [at] microsoft dot com.

Comment: Marked as answer, since the issue is only present when executing jobs locally.